# How to fix overriding error in font awesome with nextJS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, font-awesome

Im using FontAwesome with NextJS and Tailwind. Here is the thing after following the docs you are told to add the following code to  _app.tsx.

```
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";

config.autoAddCss = false;
```

Well that works fine expect some class called .svg-inline--fa is injected in my code that overrides my custom classes. Here are the properties that are defined.

```
.svg-inline--fa {
    display: var(--fa-display, inline-block);
    height: 1em;
    overflow: visible;
    vertical-align: -.125em;
}
```

How do i fix that? Ive been stuck on that error for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more specific by chaining selectors, e.g.

```css
body .some-other-class .svg-inline--fa {
    display: var(--fa-display, inline-block);
    height: 1em;
    overflow: visible;
    vertical-align: -.125em;
}
```

Comment: might work but I use tailwind so. I feel i should have added that in the question

Comment: Add as much as you can, it might help if you recreate the problem using codepen and share it.

Comment: I downvoted your question because there's a lack of info.